# BOM in Windows and Unix

Tags: java, byte-order-mark

I write new file with lines and need utf-8 with BOM. In my code I add BOM with the simplest way:

```
printStream.print('\ufeff');
// print lines
```

And in Win7 this method work fine, but when I execute my jar in Unix I see "?" at prolog and "utf-8 without bom encoding", how can I fix it? Crossplatform prefered...
ANSWER:

```
char[] c = {0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF};
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            printStream.write(c[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Do you view the file with the exact same tool or do you use os specific viewers? If os specific the viewer on Unix might just not interpret the bom correctly.

Comment: Same tool, Notepad ++. I generate it on Unix, add to archive and open in Windows (I have only SCP to Unix system)

Comment: Sounds like the BOM does not get written directly but becomes UTF-8 encoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure `printStream.print('\ufeff');` is the correct way of writing the utf-8 bom. You could try and write the bytes `EF BB BF` directly.

Example:

```
char[] bom = { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF }; 
//or byte[] bom= { (byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xBF };
printStream.write( bom ); //directly write the bytes
```

Comment: can you write example with printStream.print('')?

Comment: char[] c = {0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF};
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            printStream.print(c[i]);
        }
dont work

Comment: It should come out as two bytes only.

Comment: @user2271546 when you write bytes you shouldn't use `print()` methods which may apply an encoding

Comment: wow, it works, THX but I use char[], compiller dont like byte[] bom = { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF };

Comment: @user2271546 glad that it works, I'll update the answer to use `char[]` as well - you're right about the byte array initialization.